# How does React.cloneElement() work when you don't pass it an element?

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a react and redux tutorial in which the following code is used:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I've checked out the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) for `cloneElement()` and it only covers examples where a React component is passed as the first object, e.g. 
`{React.cloneElement(ChatWindow, this.props.children, this.props)}`.

How does the function work when you omit the initial element arg?

Comment: what s your intention in asking this? It would have no entry point for the cloning operation so it would throw an error most likely.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error. Elsewhere, the `App` component is rendered as a route with nested elements. Let me know if you need further info—I tried to keep the question focussed but I may have missed something important.